# Silent installation of second application in setup for .NET 6 project

Tags: wpf, installation, .net-6.0, setup-project

I have a .NET 6 WPF project and want to create a Windows setup project for installing this on client side. This worked well (with publishing elements of .NET 6 project).

In addition to that, I have to implement a silent pre-installation of some other applications (`.msi` files, e.g. .NET 6 Desktop Runtime).

I tried different options (added custom action of new project with `Installer.cs`), but there is always an error with an exit code 1618 (another installation is already running).

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

`Installer.cs` of `InstallerNET6DesktopRuntime` project:

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    {
        string path = SaveResource("windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.16-win-x64.exe");
        InstallNET6DesktopRuntime(path);
    }
    else
    {
        string path = SaveResource("windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.16-win-x86.exe");
        InstallNET6DesktopRuntime(path);
    }
}

private bool InstallNET6DesktopRuntime(string path)
{
    bool result = false;

    Process myProcess = new Process();

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/install /quiet /norestart";      //install automactically
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";        //run exe as administrator(Important!)

    myProcess.Start();

    myProcess.WaitForExit();

    return result;
}
```

Thank you!